# Font and favicon after chrome update

Tags: google-chrome, font-awesome, favicon, microsoft-edge

After chrome uptade ( yesterday ) I cant use fontawesome and favicon, and getting 3 errors when trying to load website.

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: data:font-woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAADT0ABMAAAAAVGgAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA…AjZJwbhshoYRggw4nhSBQvEtCImJJ0xT+1fUm7klCvL2M8kq7+VJDJDxV5T24AAAFVQS0vAAA=
OTS parsing error: incorrect file size in WOFF header

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Can anyone say me, why it stop working. It was work 2 days ago, and now is working well on microsoft edge.
Only problem is google chrome and after yesterday.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. The problem was with definition of font src
Old url

```
src: url(data:font-woff;base64,d09GRgA . . .
```

Solved url

```
src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;base64,d09GRgA . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the same issues with a MVC site - also found this on their issue tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=545924&can=8&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified